# .htaccess: redirect from http to https except on some pages?

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect all my website from http tp https except on some pages:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

ex: pages to be excluded :

> /home /user /info /mydata /ajax.php

Answer (score 2):

Add yet another `RewriteCond` directive:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(home|user|info|myta|ajax\.php)
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

---

or in a single rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(?!home|user|info|myta|ajax\.php) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```